# How to mirror / sync folders between two different computers using Google Drive Backup and Sync - without using "My Drive"?

Tags: windows, google-drive-for-desktop

Scenario:

- Computer A has 100 folders (not in "My Drive", i. e. outside of the "Google Drive")
- Computer B wants to have a copy of these folder (synched) and also synchronize back

How to do this with Google Drive (under Windows)?

How to make all 100 folders appear on Computer B?

Choosing folders on computer B creates a new "Computer" instance on Google Drive online:

[image: google drive screenshot]

Note 1: Here is a community discussions, but in my eyes there is no sufficient solution: https://support.google.com/drive/thread/4464830/how-to-sync-a-my-computer-folder-with-another-computer?hl=en

Note 2: As a direct solution I can only think of moving all 100 folders into "My Drive". But among those folders are several system folders that I cannot move (e.g. "Desktop").

In the community article, one user suggested "Add to My Drive" as a solution, but I cannot find this option:

[image: add to my drive]

Comment: How are the two computers connected? Via internet or local network?

Comment: Two different cities. Internet. I start to believe there is no other way than to use "My Drive" directly and skip the files from the system folders.

Comment: There are ways to mount Google Drive like a network drive, it takes third-party software to do it without the limitations of Google Drive Backup and Sync, but it’s definitely possible. Unfortunately, software recommendations, are not allowed

Comment: Google Drive Backup and Sync was deprecated / is obsolete. The current supported client is called Google Drive for Desktop. The thread from the Google Drive community is obsolete.

Comment: Why do you don't want to use My Drive? Are you using a gmail.com account?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to My Drive, you could establish a "local" network
between the computers across the internet.
You could then use your preferred sync product between the two folders.

A good product whose free account will be enough is
[ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/).

Another option is
[Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out another way.

Comment: I spent 10 hours today to try to fix the issue. No chance... Ended up using Nextcloud...

Comment: BUT also be careful with Nextcloud. They have IMO a huge usability bug, that deletes files too! See over here: https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/2502